# C++ Method Override and Overloading (Compiler level)

Tags: c++

I know what the difference between the two. Overriding basically lets you "redefine" your a method in a child class and overloading basically lets you "redefine" your method with different arguments or parameters. I'm a little confused on what's going on under the hood though. I read that when you overload a method, the compiler will have all the overloaded methods and find the best match or report an error if none exists. This is obviously done during compile time but I'm confused on how Override works. I've read that handling overrides is extremely hard because you'll have to check if the return type matches with the class hierarchy and there can be a lot of class levels to check

(ie. class Living is the super class of Human and Animal. Human and Animal can have many derived classes which means we will have a deep level of classes).

Without getting too detailed, how does overriding work at the compiler level and why is it that overriding is done during run time and not compile time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on if the overridden method is virtual or not. If the overridden method is not virtual, then under the hood it usually works in the same way as overloading, the compiler looks at the static type of the object and calls the correct function based on that.

For objects with virtual methods a vtable is usually used. This is a collection of function pointers to the virtual methods. The reason this is done at run time is to allow for runtime polymorphism. The usual way that a vtable is generate is the compilier will generate a single vtable for each class and populate it with the required pointers at compile time and include this in the executable. The constructor will then set a hidden pointer in the class to point to the correct vtable. When looking up methods it first dereferences the hidden pointer to find the vtable then dereferences the correct slot from the vtable.

Comment: Ahhhh overriding is used for polymorphism and polymorphism is used during runtime. With this logic, it should be trivial that overriding is done during runtime!

Comment: One more question. How are the vtables made during run time and how/when is it populated with function pointers?

Comment: @JustinCase I added more detail on how vtables work.

Comment: "the new operator will then set a hidden pointer in the class to point to the correct vtable" - typically this is done by the constructor, since it's needed whether the object was new'ed or not.